# Changed router and now I can't see my NAS

Tags: networking, router, nas

I had a NAS connected to my old (belkin) router with a static ip of 10.1.1.2 and today I bought a new (billion) router and now I can't see the NAS anywhere.

The NAS is a Netgear NAS (Stora).

I have tried uninstalling it already and then reinstalling it but  when reinstalling it it detected the NAS.

any ideas appreciated

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling what? See it where? We need much more details in order to comment intelligently: Network layout, IP addresses of computers/router/NAS, which make are the NAS and router etc. etc.

Comment: @harrymc - it's a DLINK NAS and it's not working!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that your new router is configured for a LAN subnet of 192.168.0.0/24. Check its documentation or check the IP address of your computer. If that's the case, you'll have to change either the IP address of your NAS or the IP address of your router.